# Can't refresh cache on google chrome with ctrl+F5 (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I'm having problems with cache on google chrome.
When I upload fresh code on production I still see the old version on the browser.
Usually pressing CTRL+F5 solved the problem, but nowadays it's not working.

The only solution I found is open the dev tools and check "disable cache", But I cannot use this for some teammates no computer-friendly... (CTRL+F5 was nice for this type of persons)
Why it's not working now? Google chrome did an update or something?

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess (had a similar story while ago) is that your assets are rendered to the identical filenames. And because cache-control-max-age is set in the future, your assets are still seen by the browser as valid and fresh.

*Disclaimer: I assume you use webpack or other capable module bundler*

I would try appending some date-based suffix to your assets on build. That way it can be endlessly cached, and when new build is made - you get a new assets URL and the files are treated as a new entities, so cache-control has no influence on them.